# How to merge mutiple datatables with same column names

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I am working on a Project "Payroll Management. So as to display the earnings and deduction , I created two datatables which are from the same Table tbl_EmployeeSalary.

But After loading the datatables to the datasource as two diferrent tables, I gave the fields to the "Detail section" in the Crystal report. But it returns 4 rows instead of 3 rows. Thanks in advance

output should look like this

```
  earnings    value                Deduction      value
  TA           120                 PF             300
  HRA          130
```

but it returns like this

```
  earnings    value                Deduction      value
  TA           120                       PF             300
  HRA          130                       PF             300
```

I used "Suppress field"

it works for this example. But with another input something like this occured

```
      earnings    value                Deduction      value

      TA           120                 PF             300
                                       Donation        1000

      HRA          130                  PF             300
                                       Donation        1000
```

But It should be like this

```
  earnings    value                Deduction      value
  TA           120                 PF             300
  HRA          130                 Donation        1000
```

Someone Please help me

Comment: you can use suppress if duplicate feature of CR

Answer (score 0):

right click on the field which is getting duplicated and click format object and then in common tab check the Suppress if Duplicate check box

Comment: Ye i want it to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a bit typical where you are getting duplication of data because of linking problem.

I am assuming TA and PF from table 1 and PF and Donation from table 2 and for one record in table 2 there are multiple records in table 1
Solution:
You may have some filed common in both the tables now group the report with that field. and now follow below steps:
1. Now place `TA`  and `HRA` in details and take summary of the both in footer;
2. Now place `PF` and `Donation` in group footer summary.

Now you can have the correct summary as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your linking you get a one-to-many result which is why you get multiple records. 
You can try and play with your linking (try inner join or left outer join), but in your case I think that creating groups will do the trick. Create 2 groups, TRA and HRA, and place your fields in the detail section. Then create a summary and put it in the group footer to display the data you want to see.

Hope that helps,

Chris